# .on('click') not playing well with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have some code here that dynamically generates a bootstrap navbar by prepending it to anything with a class of header_default. My problem is that I now want to do some .on('click') events to the dynamic navbar, although it's not really working. Specifically I've been trying to toggle some lorem ipsum when I press the brand part of the navbar. For some reason an on('click') alert will work fine this way, but nothing else will. I've tried .toggle(), .hide(), and console.log() but none of those work.

**I have tested the same click event code on the same navbar when it isn't generated by javascript and it works fine.** I am still very new to using jquery/javascript, so I'm certain I've made a fairly obvious mistake here.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--stylesheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <!--Header-->
    <nav id="page" class="header_default"></nav>

    <!--Text-->
    <div class="body-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat autem dolorum, earum adipisci magni rem. Deserunt sed aut, ad neque cum nulla rem vitae quos ducimus esse voluptatibus maxime! Vel.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
// Header
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#page').hasClass("header_default")) {
        $('<nav class="container header_default"><nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"><div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="">Brand</a></div><div><ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li><a href="about.html">About</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li></ul></div></nav></nav>')
            .prependTo( $('#page') )
    } // append navbar
}); //document.ready

//Click event
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-brand', function() {
   $('p').toggle("slow");
});
```

The .prependTo() is simply:

```
<nav class="header_default">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav><!--navbar-default-->
</nav><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be in your `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: @Jason Goemaat, not sure if it should or not. But putting it inside didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the click event initiated before element completed to ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#page').hasClass("header_default")) {
        $('<nav class="container header_default"><nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"><div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="">Brand</a></div><div><ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li><a href="about.html">About</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li></ul></div></nav></nav>').prependTo( $('#page') )
    } // append navbar

    /*--move to here---*/
    //Click event
    $(document).on('click', '.navbar-brand', function() {
       $('p').toggle("slow");
    });


}); //document.ready
```

Comment: The `.on` could be before the append, but it might have to be after the document is ready

Comment: @bekt Tried this, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @bekt there must be a small typo somewhere in my code because when I copy/pasted yours it worked for me. Let me check and see what I missed.

Comment: @RobertC you missed `#` on `<a class="navbar-brand" href="">` so it will redirect to current url.

Comment: @bekt Wow...unbelievable, it was all caused because I didn't put a #. I tried my previous code as well with a # in and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I too think it has to do with load order.  This is what worked when I tried it:

```
// Header
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#page').hasClass("header_default")) {
        $(longString)
            .prependTo( $('#page') )
    } // append navbar

    $('.navbar-brand').on('click', function() {
        $('p').toggle('slow');
    });

}); //document.ready
```

And here is an [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/850o7hrm/)

*Sidenote:  `longString` is just the contents of what you wanted to `prepend`.  I also changed the `longString` to have all of the links point to `#` so JSFiddle would play nicely with it.*

Comment: the problem ended up being a missing #.

Comment: @RobertC Heh, figured I wouldn't catch it then.  I replaced all of the urls with `#` to try and figure out what the problem was.  Good luck with the rest of your project :)